# Microsoft Report Viewer winforms version 15 assembly not packing into exe for click once

Tags: winforms, reporting-services

It used to work until the version 150.1620.0 update of the nuget package of Microsoft Reporting Services ReportViewControl Winforms. Deploying a click once I was able to run the standalone exe by itself. After the update it is requiring the dlls for the reporting services. I've tried pre reqs, interop, installing them on my computer etc... it works if you run the manifest but I need the standalone exe for the reporting services.

This is the project url
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16

see above for things I have tried